# How much protein do dogs need in their diet?

Tags: dogs, diet

I was just curious, for the interest of mixing homemade dog food and getting the correct ratios of nutrients in the food. How much protein do dogs need in their diet in order to be healthy.

I found two sources for the amounts of protein needed in a human's diet:

1. [According to the CDC](http://www.cdc.gov/nutrition/everyone/basics/protein.html#How%20much%20protein), 10-35% of your daily calories should from from protein.
2. [The wikipedia page for Complete Protein](http://www.wikiwand.com/en/Complete_protein) shows a table from the World Health Organization that explains the recommended amounts of each amino acid for a grown human. What are the amounts for a dog?

What would be the guidelines for dogs?

Comment: You might also ask about types of protein.  I believe there are several and potential sources for some are limited.

Answer (score 1):

When my dog has GI upset, he goes on a chicken and rice diet until whatever the issue is has resolved (when suggested by the vet). The ratio of chicken to rice is 1:2. With cubed, boiled chicken having about 270 calories per 1 cup and boiled rice having about 200 calories per 2 cups, that would suggest about 57% of calories should come from protein.